ChatGPT Vision - calculate tokens
According to the official documentation, for analyzing a 225x224 image, no more than 800 tokens are obtained. but in fact about 8000 tokens come out.
model: gpt-4o-mini-2024-07-18
code:
base64_image = encode_image(image_path)
response = self.client.chat.completions.create(
    model=self.model,
    messages=[
        {
        "role": "user",
        "content": [
            {
            "type": "text",
            "text": prompt,
            },
            {
            "type": "image_url",
            "image_url": {
                "url":  f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64_image}"
            },
            },
        ],
        }
    ],
    stream=True
    )

I guess I may be loading the image incorrectly, but I took the example from the documentation

In the official documentation for the model you specify, there is a calculator where you can put the size of the image. It shows that it will use 8500 tokens.
This is the official pricing page: https://openai.com/api/pricing/
As the image size is under the size of a "tile" of 512x512, the price is charged for a 512x512 image.
They count 2833 base tokens + 5667 tokens per tile (1 in this case) = 8500 tokens.
